# Selenium Chromedriver add cookie - invalid domain error

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, selenium-webdriver, pickle

I am trying to store and upload a cookie that I retrieve from a webpage via selenium.

I am new to cookies so please tell me what I am doing wrong. I am trying to learn.

I open a page up with selenium, manually log in, peform some action then wait.. (and my code is set to get cookies after 30 seconds )

```
print "adding cookies now"
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

after that, my cookies.pkl file looks something like this:

```
(lp0
(dp1
Vdomain
p2
V.twitter.com
p3
sVsecure
p4
I00
sVvalue
p5
V"v3:1484006785862560132892059"
p6
sVexpiry
p7
F1531267585.126113
sVpath
p8
# more lines
```

after this `log_in_and_store()`, i try to reopen the page with selenium while loading this cookies. If done correctly, it should open to the page i left off! Not the login page.

When I try uploading my cookies to the webpage like this:

```
driver.get('http://www.website.com')
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    print cookie
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

add_cookies are throwing this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid cookie
>   domain: invalid domain:".twitter.com"   (Session info:
>   chrome=55.0.2883.95)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417412
>   (ac882d3ce7c0d99292439bf3405780058fcca0a6),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.1
>   x86_64)

I tried this already, SO PLEASE DONT LINK ME TO IT([Selenium addCookie getting Invalid Cookie Domain Exception even though I'm on the right domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149034/selenium-addcookie-getting-invalid-cookie-domain-exception-even-though-im-on-th))

Ive also tried changing chromedriver versions, changing my code a million times and banging my head against the wall. none of those worked.

Please help, thank you very much

Answer (score 30):

I was getting this error too in Py selenium.

The solution is:
First visit the home page of the website whose cookies you are trying to add.

```
    # first visit home page
    url = "https://www.website.com"
    driver.get(url)

    # delete the current cookies
    driver.delete_all_cookies()

    # add cookies from pickled-txt or a txt file
    cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
    for cookie in cookies:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)

    # visit again and you shall see your account logged in
    url = "https://www.website.com"
    driver.get(url)
```

The reason is:

1. Selenium webdriver is initialized with default url `data:`.
2. add_cookie() requires the current url to be under the same domain pattern as the cookie.
3. `data:` will not match any cookie domain

So, you get `invalid cookie domain` error.

Comment: in order for me to modify cookies successfully I had to use `driver.delete_all_cookies()` after visiting the domain and before setting the specific cookie I'm after.

Comment: yes that was the solution thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I was very much anxious with this error , Like other answers have suggested we first have to load the page then we have to load cookies and then again load the page and voila .

```
import pickle
from selenium import webdriver

def save_cookie(driver):
    with open("cookie", 'wb') as filehandler:
        pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), filehandler)
def load_cookie(driver):
     with open("cookie", 'rb') as cookiesfile:
         cookies = pickle.load(cookiesfile)
         for cookie in cookies:
             print(cookie)
             driver.add_cookie(cookie)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = 'https://www.example.com'
driver.get(url)
load_cookie(driver)
# Do you task here 
save_cookie(driver)
driver.quit()
```