# Add cookies before first request in Python3 with Selenium Firefox Webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a PKI authentication website so the first thing when opening the page is ask for the pin so I cannot set-up the already saved cookie before loading the page.

I've seen a similar solution for the chrome driver [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63220248/how-to-preload-cookies-before-first-request-with-python3-selenium-chrome-webdri) but there is no execute_cdp_cmd for the Firefox Webdriver object. Also, when trying to just load the cookie without getting the page to load, and without trying to use execute_cdp_cmd at all, I get the following error, as expected, just that is referencing chrome instead of firefox.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidCookieDomainException: Message: Document is cookie-averse
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:186:5
InvalidCookieDomainError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:326:5
GeckoDriver.prototype.addCookie@chrome://remote/content/marionette/driver.js:1931:11
```

My code is as follows:

```
import time
import os
import pickle
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Firefox("C:\\Users\\myuser\\PycharmProjects\\myproject\\")
cookie_path = "cookies.pkl"


def get_page():
    # driver.get(f"https://mypkiaythenticationpage.com")

    if not os.path.isfile(cookie_path):
        print("Cookie File not found, generating new one")
        pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
    else:
        # driver.delete_all_cookies()
        # driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.enable', {})
        cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
        for cookie in cookies:
            driver.add_cookie(cookie)
        print("Loading cookie ...")
    driver.get(f"https://mypkiaythenticationpage.com")

def save_last_cookie_state():
    print("Saving last cookie state ...")
    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))


#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_page()
    driver.get(f"https://mypkiaythenticationpage.com")
    save_last_cookie_state()
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a [`cookies.sqlite` database](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Firefox_cookie_database) in the profile assigned to the `webdriver`. `cookies.sqlite` can be generated from Selenium cookies with the following:

```py
from collections.abc import Sequence
from contextlib import closing
from typing import Any, Mapping
import os
import pickle
import sqlite3

# Generated via `sqlite3 -readonly path/to/fxprofile/cookies.sqlite ".schema"`.
# See:
# - http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Firefox_cookie_database
# - https://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Finding_the_profile_folderSQL_STATEMENT_CREATE_TABLE
SQL_STATEMENT_CREATE_TABLE = r"""
CREATE TABLE
moz_cookies (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    originAttributes TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    name TEXT,
    value TEXT,
    host TEXT,
    path TEXT,
    expiry INTEGER,
    lastAccessed INTEGER,
    creationTime INTEGER,
    isSecure INTEGER,
    isHttpOnly INTEGER,
    inBrowserElement INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    sameSite INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    rawSameSite INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    schemeMap INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT moz_uniqueid UNIQUE (name, host, path, originAttributes)
)
"""

SQL_STATEMENT_INSERT_COOKIE = r"""
INSERT INTO
  moz_cookies (
    name,
    value,
    host,
    path,
    expiry,
    lastAccessed,
    creationTime,
    isSecure,
    isHttpOnly
  )
VALUES (
    :name,
    :value,
    :domain,
    :path,
    :expiry,
    :access_time,
    :creation_time,
    :secure,
    :httponly
  );
"""


def generate_cookies_db(
    cookies: Sequence[Mapping[str, Any]],
    access_time: int,
    creation_time: int,
    db_path: str | os.PathLike,
) -> None:
    with closing(sqlite3.connect(db_path)) as connection:
        with closing(connection.cursor()) as cursor:
            cursor.execute(SQL_STATEMENT_CREATE_TABLE)
            for cookie in cookies:
                values = {
                    "access_time": access_time,
                    "creation_time": creation_time,
                    "domain": cookie.get("domain"),
                    "expiry": cookie.get("expiry"),
                    "httponly": cookie.get("httpOnly", False),
                    "name": cookie["name"],
                    "path": cookie.get("path"),
                    "secure": cookie.get("secure", False),
                    "value": cookie["value"],
                }
                cursor.execute(SQL_STATEMENT_INSERT_COOKIE, values)
        connection.commit()


def main():
    cookies_path = "cookies.pkl"
    with open("cookies.pkl", "rb") as fp:
        cookies = pickle.load(fp)
        access_time_us = int(os.path.getmtime(cookies_path) * 1_000_000)
        creation_time_us = int(os.path.getctime(cookies_path) * 1_000_000)
        generate_cookies_db(
            cookies, access_time_us, creation_time_us, "./cookies.sqlite"
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Alternatively, you can filter from an [existing profile](https://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Finding_the_profile_folder) directly with `sqlite3`:

```bash
$ sqlite3 -readonly /path/to/fxprofile/cookies.sqlite ".mode insert moz_cookies" ".schema" "SELECT * FROM moz_cookies WHERE host LIKE '%.example.com'" | sqlite3 ./cookies.sqlite
```

Note that `cookies.sqlite` will be locked while Firefox is running.

Then, copy the generated `cookies.sqlite` to a profile used by the `webdriver`:

```
$ mkdir ./profile_template
$ mv ./cookies.sqlite ./profile_template
```

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("./profiletemplate")

with webdriver.Firefox(options=options) as session:
    session.get("https://example.com")
```

This directory will be treated as read-only by Selenium, since [`webdriver.FirefoxProfile` is not persisted](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile).